# Default Metrics in Ganglia

Tags: metrics, ganglia

Can I have the list of default metrics in Ganglia? 
Example: CPU and memory are two of the default metrics collected by Ganglia. Is there a complete list of all the default metrics supported by Ganglia? 
I could not get any documentation on the same.

Answer (score 0):

Ganglia provides the following group of default system metrics stored in rrd files per cluster directories:

1. CPU statistics -  Report processors related statistics. Example: cpu user, cpu nice, cpu system, cpu io wait etc.
2. Disk statistics - Report mount points information. Example: mount points disk size, disk size available etc.
3. Memory statistics - Reports a large amount of valuable information about the Linux system’s memory. [Read about linux meminfo here](http://www.cloudibee.com/know-about-procmeminfo/)
4. Network statistics - Reports network information and data is available in the /proc/net/ directory. Read about linux /proc/net directory
5. NFS statistics - Reports nfs server and client statistics.
6. Network interface traffic - Reports interface statistics from /proc/net/dev.

All the above statistics exposes run time system information which exist in **/proc** virtual file system.[Read about proc here](http://tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html)

**NOTE:** Default python metrics files are located under  /usr/lib64/ganglia/python_modules directory in python extension.